# JSP rendering issues, before struts 2 action and after struts 2 action

Tags: java, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, struts2

I am working on struts 2 project and facing a weird issue badly need your help on that issue

1 -- I have developed a web page with bootstrap css which is actually in local
      I mean css and js files are in my local

2 -- I have developed a struts action for that jsp, when you clock a button it will call a action class and do some business logic and returns to same page

My problem is when that page loads first time css is been applied properly but after button click flow will go to struts2 config and mapped to action on return success from that action I am returining to same jsp, except this time on the same jsp css are not been properly loaded

and that action I am referring now is in a struts-school.xml which is been included into struts.xml   --  I don't believe this would be the issue but just in case

Note : it is a maven project, which is actually a web project when I started but later converted to maven

Please go through the code and images of the same jsp when it renderd before struts 2 action and after struts 2 action

### JSP  "schoolHome.jsp"

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
  <link href="CustomCssAndScript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="CustomCssAndScript/bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="CustomCssAndScript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <%@include file="schoolHeaderMenus/schoolHeader.jsp" %>
    <%@include file="schoolLeftSideMenus/sideMenu1.jsp" %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### OTHER INCLUDED JSP "schoolHeader.jsp"

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
  <link href="CustomCssAndScript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="CustomCssAndScript/bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="CustomCssAndScript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
   <style type="text/css">
    .jumbotron {
    background: #000 url("images/FotorCreated.jpg");
    height:50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ff6a00
}
</style>
<style>
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="pull-right">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                          <li class="active"><a href="#" style="color: white;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" style="color: white;">Students Managment</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" style="color: white;">Staff Managment</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" style="color: white;">Library Managment</a></li>
                          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="color: white;">  Add Members<span class="caret"></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">                            
                              <li><a href="school/addTeachersAdminAction?param=teacher"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Teacher's</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>  Add Student's</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>  Add Non-Teaching Staff</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>  Add Parent's</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>  Add Branche's</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="color: white;">  Other Managment's <span class="caret"></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">                            
                              <li><a href="logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span> Transport Managment</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span>  Non-Teaching Staff Managment</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span>  Furniture Managment</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span>  Building Managment</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  Complaints</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="color: white;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Hello, <s:property value="#session.user.articleUserName"/><span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">                            
                              <li><a href="logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Logout</a></li>
                              <li><a href="logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Update Profile</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  View your profile</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### INCLUDED OTHER JSP "sideMenu1.jsp"

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <link href="CustomCssAndScript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="CustomCssAndScript/bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="CustomCssAndScript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openMenu() {
    var div1 = document.getElementById('anchor');
    div1.style.display = "none";

     var div = document.getElementById('menuBar');
    div.style.display = "block";
}
function closeMenu() {
    var div1 = document.getElementById('anchor');
    div1.style.display = "block";

     var div = document.getElementById('menuBar');
    div.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a onclick="openMenu()" id="anchor" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"> Menu</span></a>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse col-lg-2 well" id="menuBar" style="display: none;">
    <a class="pull-right" onclick="closeMenu()" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a><br/>
        <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="color: blue;">  Dash Board<span class="caret"></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">                            
                              <li><a href="logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span> Setting's</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span>  Acadamic Detail's</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span>  Privilege's</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span>  Assign Cources</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  Enquiry List</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  Event Managment</a></li>
                            </ul>
                         </li>                        
                         <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="color: blue;">  Academic's<span class="caret"></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">                            
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span>  Subjects and Batched</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span>  Lession Planning</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span>  Time Table</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  Exams</a></li>
                              <li><a href="viewProfile"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  Notes and Assignment's</a></li>
                            </ul>
                         </li> 
                    </ul>
                </div>
           </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### struts-school.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="schoolStrutsConfig" namespace="/school" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="addTeachersAdminAction" class="baci.portal.school.schoolActions.SchoolAdminAction" method="addPeople">
            <result name="teacher">schoolHome.jsp</result>
            <result name="student">addStudent.jsp</result>
            <result name="nonteaching">addNonteaching.jsp</result>
            <result name="parent">addParent.jsp</result>
            <result name="branch">addBranch.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

### struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <!-- Login User -->
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="login" class="baci.portal.actions.UserActions" method="login">
            <result name="it">portal.jsp</result>
            <result name="school">school/schoolHome.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">index.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <!-- Posting Article -->
        <action name="postArticle" class="baci.portal.actions.ArticleAction" method="postArticle">
            <result name="success">portal.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="viewArticle" class="baci.portal.actions.ArticleAction" method="viewArticle">
            <result name="success">article.jsp</result>
        </action>   
        <action name="comment" class="baci.portal.actions.ArticleAction" method="comment">
            <result name="success">article.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="articleSolution" class="baci.portal.actions.ArticleAction" method="articleSolution">
            <result name="success">article.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="viewProfile" class="baci.portal.actions.UserActions" method="viewProfile">
            <result name="success">profile.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">index.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="logout" class="baci.portal.actions.UserActions" method="logout">
            <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">index.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="viewPublicProfile" class="baci.portal.actions.UserActions" method="viewPublicProfile">
            <result name="success">publicProfile.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">index.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="signUp" class="baci.portal.actions.UserActions" method="signUp">
            <result name="success">registration.jsp</result>
            <result name="fail">index.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="registerUser" class="baci.portal.actions.UserActions" method="registerUser">
            <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
            <result name="false">registration.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="checkAval" class="baci.portal.actions.UserActions" method="checkAval">
        </action>
        <action name="homePage" class="baci.portal.actions.UserActions" method="homePage">
            <result name="success">portal.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">index.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="publicProfile" class="baci.portal.actions.UserActions" method="publicProfile">
            <result name="success">portal.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
    <include file="/struts-school.xml"></include>
</struts>
```

[image: First part of my project structure]

[image: Second part of my project structure]

[image: Page Before struts action]

[image: Page after struts action]

Comment: Don't use scriptlets.

Comment: Hi roman, those are struts 2 tag library imports so no optios we must use scriptlets

Comment: if you understand my actual problem please let me know any solution for that

Comment: no option the solution is not possible

Comment: is it ?   Thanks for that